# Why can't I add a second term to my function (add taxonomy to body class)

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I need to see the categories in the body to call certain CSS. I tried to add a second category term to the allready excisting working code. But it won't work for the newly added category (portfolio_category). What am I doing wrong?

```
//add taxonomy to body class
 add_filter( 'body_class', 'themeprefix_add_taxonomy_class' );
 // Add taxonomy terms name to body class
function themeprefix_add_taxonomy_class( $classes ){
    if( is_singular() ) {
        global $post;
        $taxonomy_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'arbocategory',  'portfolio_category' );
        if ( $taxonomy_terms ) {
            foreach ( $taxonomy_terms as $taxonomy_term ) {
            $classes[] = 'tax_' . $taxonomy_term->slug;
            }
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/
get_the_terms() accepst two paramters $post, $taxonomy, you can't just dump multiple taconomies to the function and expect it to work. you need to run get_the_terms() twice.

```
function themeprefix_add_taxonomy_class( $classes ){
    if( is_singular() ) {
        global $post;
        $terms = array('arbocategory', 'portfolio_category');
        foreach ($terms as $t) {
            $taxonomy_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $t );
                if (is_array($taxonomy_terms) && count($taxonomy_terms)>0) {
                foreach ( $taxonomy_terms as $taxonomy_term ) {
                    $classes[] = 'tax_' . $taxonomy_term->slug;
                }
            }
        }     
    }
    return $classes;
}
```